# Animate function in javascript, I need to animate something when I click on it so that one div goes 1 way and the other div goes the other way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

The code I am working with looks like this

```
<script>
        (function($){
            $(document).on('click', '.tile', function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.tile:not(.active):eq(0)').animate({top: -900, left: 180});
                $('.tile:not(.active):eq(1)').animate({top: 900, left: -180});
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.active', function(){
                $('.tile:not(.active):eq(0)').animate({top: 0, left: 0});
                $('.tile:not(.active):eq(1)').animate({top: 0, left: 0});
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

**I cannot work out how I can adapt this code to fit my html. My current html is this:**

```
<div class="container" id= "left" >
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>HAIR</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class= "container" id= "center">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>BEAUTY<a/></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id= "right">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>BARBERS</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Can anyone please help?
Many thanks**

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

```
<script>
        (function($){
            $(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.container:not(.active):eq(0)').animate({top: -900, left: 180});
                $('.container:not(.active):eq(1)').animate({top: 900, left: -180});
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.active', function(){
                $('.container:not(.active):eq(0)').animate({top: 0, left: 0});
                $('.container:not(.active):eq(1)').animate({top: 0, left: 0});
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Cheers Dom, much appreciated. It still doesn't seem to be working which is baffling me.
Would you be able to look at my code at all please? Thankyou
Clarke